# How can I solve this issue painting path in Ios in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

Please help me to solve this issue painting the path in google maps lib

I tried to compile codenameone lib but I have problem compiling too.

[image]

```
public void paintPath(Coord originL, Coord destinationL) {

String methodName = "paintPath";

try {
    String apiKey = ForceSOS.getApiKey();
    Log.i(TAG, methodName+"()->apiKey:" + apiKey);
    if (originL!= null && destinationL != null) {
        Utils.getRoutesEncodedAsync(apiKey, originL, destinationL, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSucess(Object value) {
                String encoded = (String) value;
                Coord[] coords = Utils.decodePath(encoded);
                if (mc != null) {
                    mc.setPathStrokeColor(0xFF0000);
                    mc.setPathStrokeWidth(5);
                    
                    if (moCurrPath!=null)
                        mc.removeMapObject(moCurrPath);
                   
                    moCurrPath = mc.addPath(coords);
                    //ForceSOS.insertLogEvent("0", "0", "0", "0", "adding route:["+originL.getLatitude()+","+originL.getLongitude()+ " to "+destinationL.getLatitude()+","+destinationL.getLongitude()+"]"+(coords!=null?"ok":"null") +":key:"+apiKey, TAG, methodName);
                    
                    
                }else{
                    ForceSOS.insertLogEvent("0", "0", "0", "0", "null map component" , TAG, methodName);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Object sender, Throwable err, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                ForceSOS.insertLogEvent("0", "0", "0", "0", "E1:"+errorMessage , TAG, methodName);
            }
        });
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.eRR(TAG, true, "Error3:" + e.toString(),methodName);
}
}

public static DataServerEvent getRoutesEncodedAsync(String key, Coord src, Coord dest, Callback callback) {

    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json";
    DataServerEvent dse1 = new DataServerEvent(new OnGetDataServerEvent() {

        @Override
        public void eventDataFromServer(int idEvent, Map<String, Object> response) {

            String ret = "";
            if (response.get("routes") != null) {
                ArrayList routes = (ArrayList) response.get("routes");
                if (routes.size() > 0) {
                    ret = ((LinkedHashMap) ((LinkedHashMap) ((ArrayList) response.get("routes")).get(0)).get("overview_polyline")).get("points").toString();
                }
            }
            callback.onSucess(ret);
        }

    }, "gettingPath", url, EVENT_ID.PAINT_MAP_PATH, TimeOuts.TO_10SECS, DataServerEvent.RESPONSE.JSON);
    dse1.addArguments("key", key);
    dse1.addArguments("origin", src.getLatitude() + "," + src.getLongitude());
    dse1.addArguments("destination", dest.getLatitude() + "," + dest.getLongitude());
    dse1.start();
    return dse1;
}
```

Comment: We need the Java source code that triggered that. It looks like you called addToPath on an invalid path.

Comment: in the android side is working perfectly this issue is failing next of october 2020

Comment: I noticed you didn't check if coords is null or invalid here.

Comment: this isn't the problem. This coor doesn't null because I tested in reals devices iphone xs ios 14.2 an I logged using the commented method ForceSOS.insertLogEvent in my test case. I will send you a simple test case.

Comment: follow this issue : https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/issues/40

Comment: I assigned this for evaluation